# Automated testing with Visual Studio 2012 for test framework telerik

Tags: visual-studio-2012, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

How do I generate a test in Visual Studio 2012 with the framework of telerik for this command line:

```html
<span class = "widget-k k k-dropdown-header" style = "width: 100%;" unselectable = "on" role = "listbox" aria-haspopup = "true" aria-expanded = "false" tabindex = "0" = aria-owns "IdCorPinturaTipo_listbox" aria-disabled = "false" aria-readonly = "false" aria-busy = "false" aria-activedescendant = "IdCorPinturaTipo_option_selected">
<span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-input" unselectable="on"> PEROLIZADA </ span>
<span class="k-select" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-icon ki-arrow-s" unselectable="on"> select </ span>
</ span>
</ span>
<input id="IdCorPinturaTipo" type="text" style="width: 100%; display: none;" name="IdCorPinturaTipo" data-role="dropdownlist">
</ span>
```

Since the information is from a dropdownList and want to generate test information PEROLIZADA.

I've tried several codes to generate this line:

```html
<span class="k-input" unselectable="on"> PEROLIZADA </ span>
```

This is one of the examples that I tried to generate test the above information.

```cs
Find.ByExpression<HtmlAnchor>("class=k-input", "unselectable=on", "tabindex=-1", "id=IdCorPinturaTipo_option_selected").InnerText("PEROLIZADA");
```

Comment: Hi Michael - what goes wrong with the code you've tried? Does it fail to locate the element?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this approach](https://github.com/theqaangel/custom-test-framework). There is detailed information in the [wiki](https://github.com/theqaangel/custom-test-framework/wiki).

Answer (score -2):

string str = "PEROLIZADA";
Find.ByExpression("class=k-input", "unselectable=on", "textcontent="+str);